# Combine CSVs in Multiple Sub-folders Using Command Line

Tags: cmd

I'm trying to come up with something simple to combine numerous csv files in multiple subfolders.

I've put together this code but it doesn't drill down into the subfolders. Is it possible to do that?

```
cd c:\Users\[user]\AppData\Roaming\[software]\[name of user data folder for installation]\Reports\
findstr "^" *.csv >[Combined file name].csv
```

Comment: See what `findstr /?` tells you about the `/s` switch.

Comment: Please don't use tag `[dos]` for Windows command prompt questions; I edited your question to tag it with `[cmd]` instead. Although many people call the Windows command prompt "DOS",  that is technically wrong since it isn't DOS anymore (not since Windows XP)